# Flutter focused menu working in emulator but not working in real deivce

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, android-emulator

In Flutter I have an Focus Menu from the following package: https://pub.dev/packages/focused_menu/install. I have the latest version and the code looks alright. The problem however is that it works on both IOS and android emulators, but it doesn't work on my or my friends Iphones. The Focused menu is displayed but the items are empty and do not contain any text or icons.

```
  List<FocusedMenuItem>? createLanguages() {
    List<FocusedMenuItem> languages = [
      FocusedMenuItem(title: Text("Share"),trailingIcon: Icon(Icons.share) ,onPressed: (){}),
      FocusedMenuItem(title: Text("Share2"),trailingIcon: Icon(Icons.share) ,onPressed: (){}),
      FocusedMenuItem(title: Text("Share3"),trailingIcon: Icon(Icons.share) ,onPressed: (){}),
    ];
    return languages;
  }
```

Where the createLanguages is used below:

```
              FocusedMenuHolder(
                child: Image.asset(
                  country_flags[whichFlag],
                  package: 'country_icons',
                  width: 1.25 * AppBar().preferredSize.height,
                  height: 1.25 * AppBar().preferredSize.height,
                ),
                menuItems: createLanguages()!,
                onPressed: () {
                  },
                openWithTap: true,
              )
```

I also tried to do it directly in the FocusedMenuHolder but that dit not work also.[Picture of FocuesMenuHolder with empty items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KO0c.jpg)

```
FocusedMenuHolder(
                child: Image.asset(
                  country_flags[whichFlag],
                  package: 'country_icons',
                  width: 1.25 * AppBar().preferredSize.height,
                  height: 1.25 * AppBar().preferredSize.height,
                ),
                menuItems: <FocusedMenuItem>[
                  FocusedMenuItem(title: Text("Share"),trailingIcon: Icon(Icons.share) ,onPressed: (){}),
                  FocusedMenuItem(title: Text("Share2"),trailingIcon: Icon(Icons.share) ,onPressed: (){}),
                  FocusedMenuItem(title: Text("Share3"),trailingIcon: Icon(Icons.share) ,onPressed: (){}),
                ],
                onPressed: () {
                  },
                openWithTap: true,
              )
```

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer,

Because my phone was on dark mode the text in the items were not visible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I couldn't see the items texts in chrome or my emulators. Changed ThemeData.dark to ThemeData.light and it worked as the op suggested:

```
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
```